# Would the diadem possess anyone who tried to wear it?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter, we frequently see dark objects—in particular, Horcruxes—possessing anyone who gets too close to it. Although this is typically emotionally—through Ginny’s dependence on Tom Riddle’s diary, and Slytherin’s locket sensing Ron’s insecurity and resentment for Harry—having close physical contact with a Horcrux can amplify its effects.

In this vein, **Would Rowena Ravenclaw’s diadem possess anyone who tried it on?**

Comment: it might have had a similar curse as the ring, and just cursed the wearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Not necessarily

Without a doubt, the piece of soul within the diadem *could* possess someone, under the right circumstances, for this is a power possessed by all Horcruxes:

> “Hang on,” said Ron, frowning. “The bit of soul in that diary was
> possessing Ginny, wasn’t it? How does that work, then?”
>
> “While the magical container is still intact, the bit of soul inside
> it can flit in and out of someone if they get too close to the object.
> I don’t mean holding it for long, it’s nothing to do with touching
> it,” she added before Ron could speak.
> “I mean close emotionally.
> Ginny poured her heart out into that diary, she made herself
> incredibly vulnerable. You’re in trouble if you get too fond of or
> dependent on the Horcrux.”
>
> <sub>—*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*</sub>

As Hermione, says, shortly after reading various books on Horcruxes, emotional closeness is the key element in being possessed by a Horcrux. There may be *some* element of physical proximity required, since some of the locket Horcrux’s other effects depended on whether someone was wearing it. However, the key element certainly seems to be how much of a connection one has to the Horcrux *emotionally*.

**As such, it seems unlikely that the diadem could possess anyone who simply tried it on**, any more than the locket was able to possess Harry, Hermione, or indeed really Ron, despite their constant physical contact with it, or any more than Hufflepuff’s Cup tried to possess Harry when he touched it. **Even if it tried, it would undoubtedly fail.** Now, if someone had been seeking the diadem for its wisdom-granting properties and pinned all their hopes on it, on the other hand, perhaps....

Comment: Another example of this is Dumbledore. He put on his brother's ring and was cursed - he wasn't close to the ring *itself*, more to the idea it symbolized (i.e. his relationship to his brother).